# Is neo4j 2 compatible with on jdk 6?

Tags: java, neo4j

Is neo4j 2.0 exclusively for jdk 7 ? Our firm runs on jdk 1.6 and we can not upgrade to jdk 7 till next year.
Any way to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [the release notes](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/packaging/standalone/standalone-community/src/main/distribution/text/community/CHANGES.txt) it looks like Java 7 is required:

```
2.0.0-M04
---------
Kernel:
  o BREAKING CHANGE: Require Java 7
```

I'm not a Neo4j developer, but based on Java developer experience in general, when a major dependency update like this is introduced, I find it unlikely to be rolled back.

Comment: Tried using it with Java 6, result when using code from `neo4j-kernel-2.0.0-M05.jar` is `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/neo4j/graphdb/... : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0` meaning it is actually compiled for Java 7 and wont' work with 6. Quite early to require 7...

Comment: I wish they release a neo2 for java 6 :(

Comment: Java6 is officially End Of Life. Supporting it in future versions of Neo4j is just not responsible from a maintenance PoV.

Comment: Totally understand that Peter. Thanks !